# Differentiation under the integral sign when derivative exists only almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Regarding the Theorem 3 from [here](http://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign) (or [pdf ver.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150527012835/http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/38599.pdf)).

> Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\Omega$ be a measure space. Suppose that a function $f\colon X\times\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1. $f(x,\omega)$ is a measurable function of $x$ and $\omega$ jointly, and is integrable over $\omega$,  for almost all $x\in X$ held fixed.

2. For almost all $\omega\in\Omega$, $f(x,\omega)$ is an absolutely continuous function of $x$. (This guarantees that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,\omega)$
   exists almost everywhere.)

> 

3. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,\omega)$ is "locally integrable" --- that is, for all compact intervals $[a,b]\subset X$:

> $$
> \int_a^b\!\!\int_{\Omega}\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,\omega) \right| d\omega dx<\infty.
> $$
> Then, $\int_\Omega f(x,\omega)d\omega$ is an absolutely continuous function of $x$, and for almost every $x\in X$, its derivatives exists and is given by
> $$
> \frac{d}{dx}\int_{\Omega}f(x,\omega)d\omega
> =
> \int_{\Omega}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,\omega)d\omega.
> $$

**Question 1:** I do not see how to show $\int_\Omega f(x,\omega)d\omega$ is absolutely continuous in $x$.

**Question 2:** I also wonder where I can find this result preferably in a book or a paper etc.

====================================================

Here is my thought:
Notations basically follow the plametmath note by Steven Cheng (the link above).

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be the measure space and $(a,b):=X\subset\mathbb{R}$.

For $\mu$-almost all $\omega\in \Omega$, we assumed that $f(\cdot,\omega)$ is an absolutely continuous function in the first variable.

Hence for a.e.-$x$ we have
\begin{align}
f(x,\omega)&=f(a,\omega)+\int_{a}^x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,\omega)\,dy
\end{align}

Letting $G(x):=\int_{a}^x\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,\omega)\,
d\mu(\omega ){d}y$ and $g(x):=\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,\omega)\,
d\mu(\omega )$ by virtue of Lebesgue differentiation theorem for the indefinite integral, for a.e. $x$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,\omega)d\mu(\omega )
&=g(x)=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G(x)
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{\Omega}\int_{a}^x
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,\omega)\,
dyd\mu(\omega ).
\end{align}
where the last equality is ok from the assumption
$
\int_{\Omega}\int_{a}^x\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
 f(y,\omega)\right|
\,dyd\mu(\omega )
 <\infty
$. Adding $0=\frac{d}{d  t}\int_{\Omega}f(a,\omega)d\mu(\omega )$ to the above yields
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,\omega)d\mu(\omega )
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_{\Omega}\left\{
\int_{a}^x
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,\omega)\,
dy+f(a,\omega)\right\}d\mu(\omega )
\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{\Omega}
f(x,\omega)d\mu(\omega ).
\end{align}
I think the RHS exists for almost every $x$ because LHS does, which is the second claim of Theorem 3. I am not sure if I can immediately say $\int_\Omega f(x,\omega)d\omega$ is AC in $x$, which is the first claim of 3., Theorem 3.

Comment: replaced the link, thanks!